# Pegar array de dados JSON e imprimir com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, json

Tenho um JSON no seguinte formato:

```
{
    "representantes":
    [
        {
        "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
        "endereco": "Alameda dos Anjos",
        "cep":      "12345-000",
        "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
        "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
        "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        }   
    ]
}
```

Basicamente, esses são os dados a serem usados para imprimir em uma `div`, mas existem representantes em diversos estados. Então, como eu faria isso com JSON? Como criar um array de representantes por estado com os dados acima? E como imprimir na `div`?

preview de como ficaria impresso:
[image: preview de como ficaria os dados impressos]
como podem ver, tem mais estados também, além de SP para imprimir

Comment: Nos ajude a ajudá-lo dando um exemplo de como ficaria a div com os dados já impressos ;)

Comment: Nota: Troque as informações sensíveis de seu código por informações abstratas. Você nunca sabe quais as intenções de quem lê seu código.

Comment: Você tem a lista por estado separadamente, ou precisa extrair a informação da string de endereço?

Comment: ai está cavalheiros o exemplo. @André o que você quis dizer?  a lista é por estado, so nao sei como eu organizaria isso em json.

Comment: @LeandroRuel Só falei por tirar informações reais do exemplo. Substituir por "FOO LTDA" como você fez.

Comment: editei minha resposta @LeandroRuel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Se quiser, recomendo utilizar um JSON Parser para facilmente criar e modificar JSON's como este aqui:

> [JSON Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Para criar um `Array` em [json](/questions/tagged/json) organizado por estados utilize seu objeto da seguinte maneira:

```
{
    "estado":
    [
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SP",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SC",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de RJ",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        }
    ]
}
```

Assim você teria 3 objetos(representantes) no array `estado` do seu JSON, do qual foi apenas um exemplo, você pode ter quantos objetos quiser em um Array JSON.

Para imprimir na div faria o seguinte:

**Primeiro:** Armazene o objeto JSON em uma variável para poder acessar e também para identificar do qual são representantes desta maneira:

```js
var representante = {
    "estado":
    [
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SP",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de SC",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        },
        {
             "nome":     "Foo LTDA",
             "endereco": "Endereço de RJ",
             "cep":      "12345-000",
             "telefone": "(11) 1234-1234",
             "site":     "www.foo.com.br",
             "email":    "email@foo.com.br"
        }
    ]
}
```

E depois você pode utilizar de um laço de repetição para armazenar o conteúdo que quiser em sua `<div>`, acessando `representante` desta forma:

```js
var len               = representante.estado.length,
    aryRepresentantes = [];
for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
  var nome     = representante.estado[i].nome;
  var endereco = representante.estado[i].endereco;
  var cep      = representante.estado[i].cep;
  var telefone = representante.estado[i].telefone;
  var site     = representante.estado[i].site;
  var email    = representante.estado[i].email;
  var strHTML  = "<b>"+nome+"<b>"+
                 "<br>End.: "+endereco+
                 "<br>CEP: "+cep+
                 "<br>Fone: "+telefone+
                 "<br>Site: "+site+
                 "<br>E-mail: "+email;
  aryRepresentantes.push(strHTML);
}
```

Dessa forma você teria um array de por exemplo 3 estados, que seriam `representante.estado[0]` o estado de `SP`, `representante.estado[1]` o estado de `SC` e `representante.estado[2]` o estado de `RJ`. Você pode fazer um array de estados para identificar qual é qual ou apenas utilizar um laço de repetição comum, porém vou explicar como se estivesse utilizando o array de Estados:

```
function preencheDados(aryRepresentantes){
    var aryUF = ["SP","SC","RJ"];
    for (var i=0; i < aryUF.length; i++){
      $('#div'+aryUF[i]).html(aryRepresentantes[i]);
    }
}
```

## Importante:

Desta forma nomeie o ID de suas divs para `<div id="divSP">`,`<div id="divSC">`,`<div id="divRJ">` e automaticamente o conteúdo irá para dentro delas ao executar a seguinte função:

```
preencheDados(aryRepresentantes); //nota que o aryRepresentantes foi declarado logo acima no meu laço de repetição lembra? você tem que passar ele como parâmetro.
```

Como você pode ver, aí dependendo de como está seu código [html](/questions/tagged/html) e como está seu projeto você pode adaptar um pouco o código que eu propus acima, de acordo com sua necessidade, mas o conceito é este.

Comment: como faria se fosse por estado?

Comment: Então você tem que organizar `representantes` em um array `estados` contendo todos os estados referentes, irei editar minha resposta com o JSON que você quer.

Comment: no caso no array "estado" eu teria que colocar o nome do estado, Ex: São paulo, e imprimir na divSP? o mesmo código serve se o JSON for um arquivo externo?

Comment: Na verdade, você só tem que preencher o `aryUF` com todos os estados que você usa, **na mesma ordem do JSON(muito importante)**, e nomear suas div's como div `UF` por exemplo `divSP`, `divSC`, `divRJ` - e sim funciona se o JSON for um arquivo externo, só tem que estar em ordem.

Comment: Porque você não mostra seu HTML? facilita muito pra te explicar. - edite sua pergunta e o coloque lá

Comment: ocorre um erro aqui, não tá faltando o "+" para concatenar a variável **"aryUF[i]"**?

Comment: Opa cara, isso mesmo, desculpa eu nem vi :p vou arrumar ali - ja arrumei

Comment: antes do loop "for" a variável "len" é terminada com vírgula mesmo?

Comment: Sim, pois você pode declarar várias variáveis como `var` desta forma, se fosse `;` eu teria que colocar `var` no inicio de cada variavel que eu fosse declarar :)

Answer (score 1):

Você talvez teria que ter uma propriedade no representante indicando a qual estado ele pertence, e deveria filtrar sua lista de representantes por estado,
você pode fazer isso na mão com um for e criando uma nova lista já filtrada, ou utilizando alguma biblioteca (eu recomendo essa [jLinq](http://www.hugoware.net/projects/jlinq)),
e ao encontrar os representantes por estado você deve fazer outro laço imprimindo-os em sua div, com o layout que você escolheu.

A lista deveria ser semelhante a essa:

```
var representantes = [{
    "nome" : "Foo LTDA",
    "endereco" : "Alameda dos Anjos",
    "cep" : "12345-000",
    "telefone" : "(11) 1234-1234",
    "site" : "www.foo.com.br",
    "email" : "email@foo.com.br",
    "uf": "SP"
}, {
    "nome" : "Foo LTDA",
    "endereco" : "Alameda dos Anjos",
    "cep" : "12345-000",
    "telefone" : "(11) 1234-1234",
    "site" : "www.foo.com.br",
    "email" : "email@foo.com.br",
    "uf": "SP"
}, {
    "nome" : "Foo LTDA",
    "endereco" : "Alameda dos Anjos",
    "cep" : "12345-000",
    "telefone" : "(11) 1234-1234",
    "site" : "www.foo.com.br",
    "email" : "email@foo.com.br",
    "uf": "SP"
}];
```