# Como transformar dados em array com JSON?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Tenho que pegar os dados que estão sendo acumulados na variável `valore` e transformá-los em um array pra que possa pegá-los usando `HttpRequest` em uma página HTML. Como faço isso?

```js
// Classe para chamar o JSON.
function json(){
 var qtd;
 var retorno;

 // Resgatar valores.
 json.prototype.resgatarValores = function(){
  $('#resultado').html('Carregando dados...');

  // Estrutura de resultado.
  $.getJSON('/webpro/webadm/lncidjson', function(data){
   this.qtd = data.usuarios.length - 1;
   this.valore = '';
   this.label = '';

   for (i = 0; i < this.qtd; i++){
    if(i == (this.qtd - 1)) {
     this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor;
     this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr;
    } 
    else {
     this.valore += data.usuarios[i].valor + ',';
     this.label += data.usuarios[i].descr + ',';
    }
   }

   $('#valor').html(this.valore);
   $('#label').html(this.label);
  });

 }

}

// Objeto.
var obj = new json();
obj.resgatarValores();
```

Comment: Para transformar um objeto em json não precisa criar uma classe, javascript já faz isso de forma nativa.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42809/14674 , http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5656/14674

Comment: Os valores ainda não são um array eles estãoo só sendo atribuidos a variavel.

Comment: Você pode usar métodos nativos para transformar (parsear) as informações em um JSON.

`var seuJson = JSON.parse(valore);`

Comment: Dependendo a forma de como seu objeto estiver é claro, se não você precisará formata-lo para parsear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
//obj.resgatarValores();
var obj= [{nome:"Marcelo",idade:20},{nome:"Teste",idade:90}];

var b =JSON.stringify(obj);
document.writeln(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver usando JQUERY...
Sua resposta está na documentação :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pode fazer essa conversão na camada web, como apresentado pelo user3120449, como fazer no backend dependendo da linguagem usada, no .NET temos a classe JavaScriptSerializer que realiza o trabalho.

```
    var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
           {
               { "emailSend", textBox1.Text },
               { "toEmail", textBox2.Text }
           };

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);
    MessageBox.Show(json);
```